# Can't swap Fn and Ctrl keys in my Lenovo T14

Tags: laptop, keyboard, bios, fn-key

I tried following both steps listed here: https://support.lenovo.com/br/en/solutions/ht074187-how-to-swap-the-fn-function-and-ctrl-control-keyboard-keys-in-bios

There is no such option in Control Panel to swap them. I do see an option to change them when I enter BIOS but BIOS simply doesn't let me click anything. I can only hover over the options. I click ad nothing works. The setting doesn't change from off to on. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to navigate to the option in BIOS using your keyboard? Usually, you cannot use your mouse in BIOS, this option is relatively new, and maybe it doesn't work for this option

Comment: Can you please copy the relevant part of that link into your question? The link may become unavailable and without it, your question will not be understandable anymore. AND: Not many people will follow a link in a question just to fully understand it.

Comment: you can always use the keyboard to navigate in a bios setup ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you see carefully in the link you provide, you can try swapping them from BIOS instead of Windows. I have tested this and it is working.